# VirtualBox: trying to boot Win XP in Safe Mode: how to do ctrl-alt-delete?

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard

I am trying to boot a Win XP Pro VM in Safe Mode in Virtual Box 4.1.4

I used DISK2VHD to create the VHD. The VHD is 95GB on disk but VirtualBox reports it as 145GB.  The boot hangs, so I'm trying to use Safe Mode so see what's up.

Is this possible? To boot Win XP in Safe Mode CTRL-ALT-DELETE is required, but Windows 7 is intercepting the keyboard, even when the bottom right hand corner keyboard-capture icon of VirtualBox is indicating that the keyboard is NOT being captured by the Host OS. So I gather that CTRL-ALT-DELETE remains with the host O/S?

Comment: I found the answer--there's an Insert CTRL-ALT-DELETE option on the Machine menu.

Answer (score 3):

You can send a CTRL-ALT-DELETE to your VM by selecting `Insert Ctrl-Alt-Del` from the `Machine` menu or you can type <kbd>host</kbd><kbd>del</kbd>. I think the <kbd>host</kbd> key is right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with Iain--also you don't need to Ctrl-Alt-Del for Safe Mode in any case. Just hit F8 during the boot process.

Answer (score 0):

A hard wired old school mac keyboard works perfectly, one from an old "Silver" which came out after the "blue and white"

I tried getting F8 to work with the newer bluetooth keyboards for longer than I admit.  The old USB...worked the first time.